# Can I enter the UK prior to the start of my student visa?

Tags: visas, uk, australia

I am an Australian uni student doing a 6 week course in London in October which I have applied for a Tier 4 visa for. I have also booked a 1 month trip through Europe prior to the start of my student visa, however, I land in London on the 1st day and leave the following day to start the 1 month holiday.

Can I enter the UK first as a standard tourist leave the following day, and then enter 3 weeks later on my Tier 4 student visa? I'm worried that Border Security will refuse me entry and deport me home before I can even start my holiday!

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95853/50234) by @GayotFow for a similar question by a visa national. The answer advises against such a move without keeping your institute in the loop.

Comment: I stand corrected :)

Comment: Per the comment by @RedBaron (to whom thanks) I will mark this as a duplicate. If you examine the linked material and you think your situation differs, and you can make your question unique, then edit your question and ping me, or cast a 'reopen' vote, thanks

Comment: @GayotFow For a one way traveler from country A looking for a short break in the UK (say one week) en route to a country B, when denied entry into the UK, will UK immigration put you on a flight onward to B (you are a citizen of both A & B) for which you have a ticket at a future date, or will they return you to A although you do not possess a return ticket to A? If they do return you to A, are you considered to _left the UK voluntarily, at the expense (directly or indirectly) of the Secretary of State,_ in which case you may face a 5 year ban since you did not have a return ticket?