# Can I apply for a student visa to the UK when another visa is still valid?

Tags: visas, uk

I am from China, and I need go to the UK for three weeks next month. Since a visit or business visa could allow me to enter within 6 months, the visa I obtained will be valid until April.

However, I am going to apply for a  General Student Visa in February to study, which means my business/traveling visa will still be valid when applying for the student visa.

As far as I know, one cannot obtain two visas at the same time, so I have two questions:

1. Which visa type (visit or business) is it better to apply for, the first time going to the UK?
2. Would it be risky to apply for a student visa if another visa is valid, when applying for the second time?

Comment: The type of visa you should apply for entirely depends on your reasons for coming to the UK - a Standard Visitor Visa isnt suitable for many business activities, while a Business visa may restrict non-business activities...

Comment: You really should read the following question, which is very similar to yours: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95790/can-i-apply-for-both-uk-tier-4-and-visitor-visa

Comment: the general purpose is to visit but the traveling will also last from 6 month to 2 years, i fear this would make a conflict to student visa